# Maven-Pax-Plugin and Gemini Blueprint /Spring DM

Tags: eclipse-virgo, spring-dm, blueprint-osgi, pax-runner, eclipse-gemini

following situation: We are developing an OSGi-application and the final porduct should be using Eclipse Virgo.

To get in touch with OSGi and Spring i am now investigating the OSGi Blueprint concept.
I am trying to use the maven-pax-plugin and Gemini Blueprint/Spring-DM but when i run mvn pax:provision i get the following error:

```
      ___
    /  /
   /  / Oops, there has been a problem!
  /  /  
 /__/   org.ops4j.pax.runner.platform.PlatformException:
[mvn:http://maven.springframework.org/milestone!org.springframework.osgi/spring-osgi- 
annotation/2.0.0.M1] could not be downloaded


<plugin>
    <groupId>org.ops4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-pax-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.5</version>
            <configuration>
                <provision>
                    <param>--profiles=spring.dm</param>
                    <param>--platform=equinox</param>
                </provision>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

So how can i enable Gemini Blueprint or Spring DM with pax?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any proxy settings? I think the proxy is not allowing you to download the jars.